# Embedded images not showing in outlook while it's showing in Browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook, html-email

> here i am trying to Embeds a image in my outlook but the image is not
>   coming in outlook and when i do the view source and run it as
>   html.image shows. need help.in this code i have convert image to byte
>   base 64.
>   [!IMAGE IN OUTLOOK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stxSM.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stxSM.png) USING 2016 OUTLOOK

```
private static void SendNotificationEmail(string p_TenantName, string p_TenantEmail, string p_Gmap_code, string p_ThemeEmailFrom, int p_remaindays, int p_contactid, string p_date)
{
Common.Email email = default(Common.Email);
string body = null;
string DexuslogoImage1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"Images\\Dexus_Notce_Logo.png");
string DexuslogoImage2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images\\DexusTenantNotice.png");
bodys += "src='" + writeImageToString(DexuslogoImage2) +
} 

public static string writeImageToString(string img)
{
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(img);
    dynamic b64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    dynamic dataUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + b64String;
    return dataUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Embedded images aren't supported in Outlook** (as well as a few other email clients). It's safest and best practice to reference `.jpg|.png|.gif` files remotely using `<img src="http://www.website.com/path/to/image.jpg">`.

Here's a breakdown of email client support for embedded images:

[image]
[source](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2013/02/embedded-images-in-html-email/)