# Email issue with inline image

Tags: html, html-email, email-attachments

I am having an issue with emails i am sending via the Microsoft Graph API. When i send a message which includes a signature as an inline image it for some reason shows the image as well as the attachment in the message body. In Apples mail client i get the image and below a placeholder to Tap to download below. In Outlook mobile mail on iphone i get a big blank image and below the signature png. Then in my Desktop client i see the image as desired. Below is the code how i specify the image as inline

```
 <p style="line-height: 24px">
 <img width=400  id="Picture_x0020_1" src="cid:3db07156-343b-4ed8-b2b3-7a4f5cdda90b" alt=logoemail>
 </p>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008440/embedded-images-not-showing-in-outlook-while-its-showing-in-browser

Comment: That’s not my issues as one of the client who is listed as supported has the issue which is Apple iOS mail client.

Comment: Embedded images don't work. Try hosting them instead. If embedding worked, I would be sending terrabytes of images attached to emails every month.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add sections to your email similar to this:

```
... header ...
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="Image_20190308"
--Image_20190308
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="this_is_the_html_part"
--this_is_the_html_part
<p style="line-height: 24px">
<img width=400  id="Picture_x0020_1" src="cid:3db07156-343b-4ed8-b2b3-7a4f5cdda90b" alt=logoemail>
</p>
--this_is_the_html_part--
--Image_20190308
Content-Type: image/gif; name="original_name.gif"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="original_name.gif"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <3db07156-343b-4ed8-b2b3-7a4f5cdda90b>
X-Attachment-Id: 3db07156-343b-4ed8-b2b3-7a4f5cdda90b

... insert base64 data here
--Image_20190308--
```

Comment: That’s wrong, this part is handled by the ms graph api of office 365, I have to send the image as an attachment via base 64 encoding and then use the cid to refer to the attachment