# Unable to attach images on the message body powershell send email

Tags: html, powershell, image, email

Pleae assist, I'm tring to send email with screenshoots on the message body but i keep getting an error. Images do exist in the folder. Any advise or guidance will be higly appriciated. Thanks in advance.

```
$screenshots = get-childitem C:\Test\Screenshots | Where-Object name -like "*.bmp"

$body = @()
foreach($screenshot in $screenshots){
    $filename = [system.io.path]::GetFileName($screenshot.FullName)
    $body += "<br /><img src='" + $filename + "'/><br />"
}
$body = $body | Out-String
```

Error i get:
Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is
not null or empty, and then try the command again.

I want to have the pictures attached on the message body. I might be adding more picture later so it will be best to use the for loop to get all the pictures in the folder.

Comment: Attachments is HTML MIME.  Each MIME attachment starts with two dashes on a new line.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)

Comment: [Answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837468/embed-images-in-email-and-send-via-powershell)

Comment: You can add an image attachment to an email or display the image in an email. It is not clear which method you are looking for.  My solution is adding the file as an attachment.  Re1ter solution is displaying the image.

Comment: Hi jdweng,Thanks for the response. he images must be embedded body section of the email, not as an attachment.The workaround was to do it like this(see below) $body = @()
$attachments = @()
foreach($file in $files){
    $filename = [system.io.path]::GetFileName($file.FullName)
    $attachments += $file.fullname
    $body += "<br /><img src='" + $filename + "'/><br />"but it embeds the images in the email body as expected but also add them as attachments. when I remove $attachments += $file.fullname it says attachments is nul.when I remove $attachments =@() it does not embed images anymore

Comment: Hi Re1ter.  Thanks for your response.  I looked at the information on the link. I would like to add these images using a loop instead of pointing to a single one as the images might be more in the future.               <b>This is image 1</b>
            <img src='cid:TEST1.png'>
            <b>This is image 2</b>
            <img src='cid:Test2.png'>    wanted to use a for loop to add them

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just reference *local* files from your HTML message body.

- You're already aware of the method in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52838692/45375) that [Re1ter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14720063/re1ter) has pointed you too:

  - **Add the image files *as attachments*** to the message...
  - ... and **reference them by file name via the `cid:` (Content ID) URI scheme** in the `src` attribute of the `<img>` elements.
- If you want to ***avoid* having to also provide the images *as attachments***, you have two basic options:<sup>Tip of the hat to [filimonic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1936966/filimonic) for his help.</sup>

  - Either: **Embed the actual image data** in your HTML:

    - This requires use of the `data:` URI scheme with Base64-encoded image data as the `src` attribute value of the `<img>` elements, as shown (for C#) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45008440/45375).
    - **Caveats**:

      - Displaying such images **may not be supported by all email clients** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45011270/45375) (which is from 2017 - support may have become more common since then).
      - Using the data of `.bmp` files, specifically, can be problematic in terms of size, given that the [BMP image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) *may or may not* use compression, unlike *always*-compressed formats such as [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG) and [JPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG).
  - Or: **Expose your image files *via public URLs*** (or at least ***intranet* URLs if the recipients are limited to people in the same organization)**, and use those URLs in the `src` attributes of the `<img>` elements.

    - **Caveat**:

      - As filimonic points out, in corporate environments display of images from external sources, i.e. using *public* URLs, in email clients may be *blocked* so as to prevent tracking.

Comment: Do not `Expose your image files via public URLs` as it is usually not enabled by default in enterprise clients due to `tracking` security. Embedding images as attachments is most supported way for now yet. On the other hand, author's code shows us `.bmp` files which are not best for embedding due to lack of compression. PNG or JPG is better

Comment: Good points, @filimonic, thanks. I've added caveats to the answer. Note that, at least per the linked Wikipedia article, `.bmp` files _can_ be compressed - but don't have to be.